# What is the best way to represent image nodes in a product (item) XML schema?

Tags: xml, schema

I have an XML schema that represents a product in a DB, and I am trying to figure out the best way to store the product image references as XML nodes. There will be a primary image, and then alternate images, each of them with sequences (display order). Would this be an appropriate format, or are there better approaches:

```
<item>
    <id></id>
    <images>
        <image width="" height="" href="" alt="" sequence="1" />
        <image width="" height="" href="" alt="" sequence="2" />
        <image width="" height="" href="" alt="" sequence="3" />
        <image width="" height="" href="" alt="" sequence="4" />
    </images>
</item>
```

Obviously there will be more nodes than this, but I'm not showing them all. I figured my primary image would always be the first in the sequence. The problem I'm having is that each of these images will have a thumbnail, medium and large images, so I'm thinking this needs to be broken down further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since XML elements have a natural order (that is, the order in which they appear in the XML file), it's probably redundant to include the `sequence` attribute. You can still talk about the order of the elements and there is still a "first" one for the primary product image.

So perhaps:

```
<images>
    <imageset>
        <image size="thumbnail" width="" height="" href="" alt="" />
        <image size="medium" width="" height="" href="" alt="" />
        <image size="large" width="" height="" href="" alt="" />
    </imageset>
    <imageset>
        <image size="thumbnail" width="" height="" href="" alt="" />
        <image size="medium" width="" height="" href="" alt="" />
        <image size="large" width="" height="" href="" alt="" />
    </imageset>
</images>
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend Greg's design a little:  it might be appropriate to make the image size the element name rather than making `size` an attribute, i.e.:

```
<imageset>
   <thumbnail width=""... />
   <medium width="".../>
   <large width="".../>
</imageset>
```

There are two reasons for this.

First, the name `imageset` already tells you that its child elements are going to be images, so naming the children `image` is redundant.  It's just as easy to use an XPath pattern of `imageset/*` as it is to use `imageset/image`, and it's marginally easier to write `imageset/medium` than it is to write `imageset/image[@size='medium']`.

A more important reason is that this design allows your schema to specify that an `imageset` element must contain exactly one of each type of image.  (Or that specifies that one or more image types is optional.)